# Javascript Google Place API library not getting loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

My javascript code

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.onload = function(){
var  autocomplete;

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
```

I get this error

```
Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
    at HTMLScriptElement.script.onload (mabapamavo.js:18:40)
```

The above same code works when I load the library using script tag. But I want to load the library dynamically using Javascript.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `google.maps.places` is undefined. Instead of using `script.onload`, you should be using an initialization callback, as outlined [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async).

Here's what your code should look like:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

initialize = function() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
      });
```

Comment: Thank you Brent Broome:) The above solution fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

When you load the Maps API asynchronously, you don't use an `onload` event handler. Instead, you pass the name of a callback function in the URL that loads the API. Follow [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) and it will work.